# How to check a variable is printable using print / echo?

Tags: php, echo

I've a function that receives a $mixed value.
I need to check whether it can be printed, then print that value other wise print its type.

Sample values

- $Object
- $string
- $number

And my function

```
function dmp( $value ) {
   echo $value ; 
}
```

In the above conditions when i try to print $Object, it cause a catchable error. 
Is there a way or a builtin function to check whether a value can be printed ? Or do I've to write one manually ?

Comment: Difficulty is that even objects may be 'echoable' if they implement the __toString() method in the class.

Comment: @NigelRen Yes you may use [method_exists](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php) to check that but I've found also another way to do it by using error handlers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61447722/1174405)

Answer (score 2):

You can get the type of variable using **gettype** like :

```
<?php

$data = array(1, 1., NULL, new stdClass, 'foo');

foreach ($data as $value) {
    echo gettype($value), "\n";
}

?>
```

The above example will output something similar to:

```
integer
double
NULL
object
string
```

For more details : http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettype.php

Answer (score 0):

Use this function that I wrote:

```
isPrintable($input, &$text = null) : bool
```

code below with some examples of use and checking if error handlers are not messed up.

```
<?php

/**
 * Check if $input can be echoed
 * without any problem.
 */
function isPrintable($input, &$text = null) : bool
{
    set_error_handler(function(){throw new \Exception();});
    ob_start();

    try {
        echo $input;
        $result = true;

    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $result = false;
    }

    if ($result) {
        $text = ob_get_contents();
    } else {
        $text = null;
    }

    ob_end_clean();
    restore_error_handler();
    return $result;
}

//-------- data for test -------
class PrintMe 
{
    public function __toString()
    {
        return "I have a magic power";
    }
}

$res = fopen("php://memory", 'w');
fclose($res);

$data = [
    'array' => ['array'],
    'stdClass' => (new \stdClass), 
    'PrintMe' => (new PrintMe), 
    'integer' => 1, 
    'float' => 1.5, 
    'null' => NULL,
    'bool = true' => true,
    'bool = false' => false,
    'string' => 'foo',
    'resource' => tmpfile(),
    'resource (unknown type)' => $res
];
//-------- data for test end ---

//set own err handler just for testing
set_error_handler(function(){echo "I am an error handler that should be present\n";});
//trigger an error and test if the defined error handler is present
trigger_error('', \E_USER_ERROR);

//------- check if printable -------
$resultArr = [];
foreach ($data as $name => $unknownTypeVariable) {
    $check = isPrintable($unknownTypeVariable) ? 'yes' : 'no';
    $resultArr[$name] = $check;
}

echo "\nisPrintable:\n";
print_r($resultArr);
echo "\n";
//------- check if printable end ---

//------- check if printable 2nd form -------
$resultArr = [];
foreach ($data as $name => $unknownTypeVariable) {

    if (isPrintable($unknownTypeVariable, $text)) {
        $resultArr[$name] = 'Printable: "' . $text . '"';

    } else {
        $resultArr[$name] = 'Not Printable';
    }
}

echo "\nisPrintable 2nd form:\n";
print_r($resultArr);
echo "\n";

//------- check if printable 2nd form end ---

//------- check if printable 2nd form v2 -------
$resultArr = [];
foreach ($data as $name => $unknownTypeVariable) {

    $msg = 'Not Printable';
    !isPrintable($unknownTypeVariable, $text) ?: $msg = 'Printable: "' . $text . '"';
    $resultArr[$name] = $msg;

}

echo "\nisPrintable 2nd form v2:\n";
print_r($resultArr);
echo "\n";
//------- check if printable 2nd form v2 end ---

//------- check if printable 3nd form -------
$resultArr = [];
foreach ($data as $name => $unknownTypeVariable) {

    isPrintable($unknownTypeVariable, $text);
    $msg = isset($text) ? 'Printable: "' . $text . '"' : 'Not Printable';
    $resultArr[$name] = $msg;

}

echo "\nisPrintable 3nd form v2:\n";
print_r($resultArr);
echo "\n";
//------- check if printable 3nd form end ---

//trigger an error and test if the error handler that was before is still present
trigger_error('', \E_USER_ERROR);

//restore error handler that was before testing
restore_error_handler();

//trigger a fatal error - check if restored error handler works
trigger_error('Restored error handler works', \E_USER_ERROR);
```

gives output:

```
I am an error handler that should be present

isPrintable:
Array
(
    [array] => no
    [stdClass] => no
    [PrintMe] => yes
    [integer] => yes
    [float] => yes
    [null] => yes
    [bool = true] => yes
    [bool = false] => yes
    [string] => yes
    [resource] => yes
    [resource (unknown type)] => yes
)


isPrintable 2nd form:
Array
(
    [array] => Not Printable
    [stdClass] => Not Printable
    [PrintMe] => Printable: "I have a magic power"
    [integer] => Printable: "1"
    [float] => Printable: "1.5"
    [null] => Printable: ""
    [bool = true] => Printable: "1"
    [bool = false] => Printable: ""
    [string] => Printable: "foo"
    [resource] => Printable: "Resource id #6"
    [resource (unknown type)] => Printable: "Resource id #5"
)


isPrintable 2nd form v2:
Array
(
    [array] => Not Printable
    [stdClass] => Not Printable
    [PrintMe] => Printable: "I have a magic power"
    [integer] => Printable: "1"
    [float] => Printable: "1.5"
    [null] => Printable: ""
    [bool = true] => Printable: "1"
    [bool = false] => Printable: ""
    [string] => Printable: "foo"
    [resource] => Printable: "Resource id #6"
    [resource (unknown type)] => Printable: "Resource id #5"
)


isPrintable 3nd form:
Array
(
    [array] => Not Printable
    [stdClass] => Not Printable
    [PrintMe] => Printable: "I have a magic power"
    [integer] => Printable: "1"
    [float] => Printable: "1.5"
    [null] => Printable: ""
    [bool = true] => Printable: "1"
    [bool = false] => Printable: ""
    [string] => Printable: "foo"
    [resource] => Printable: "Resource id #6"
    [resource (unknown type)] => Printable: "Resource id #5"
)

I am an error handler that should be present

Fatal error: Restored error handler works in <path-to-your-php-script> on line 130
```

All you need is just the function `isPrintable` but it will be good to save for later use the example of checking error handlers as I did so in future you can double check if `isPrintable` works as expected with an updated PHP version. Probably best way to do it would be to write a PHPUnit test covering that.

This is seriously important because not being 100% successful when playing with error handlers can give you bugs that you could track for a very long time.

the output was generated with PHP 7.3.8
`isPrintable` should also work with PHP 5 but I haven't tested it.

If you don't want to use function with error_handlers and throwing exceptions you may use [method_exists](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php) to check if an object implements [__toString](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring) method.

```
echo method_exists(new PrintMe, '__toString') ? "yes" : "no";
```

prints "yes";

```
echo method_exists(new \stdClass, '__toString') ? "yes" : "no";
```

prints "no"

and use [is_array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php) to check if variable is an array.

or probably it would be better to use [gettype](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gettype.php) to get type of variable and check it with a whitelist of types you want to print + method_exists with __toString if you want also print objects that implement __toString.

`isPrintable2` gives the same results as `isPrintable` but does not use error handler nor exceptions so it should be faster. However it works thanks to known list of variable types at the time it was written so in future may throw an InvalidArgumentException. But if it does then you will need just update the `$knownListArr` with that new type, and `$printableListArr` if you wanted to print it.

```
/**
 * Check if $input can be echoed
 * without any problem.
 */
function isPrintable2($input, &$text = null) : bool
{
    $result = true;
    $type = gettype($input);

    $knownListArr = [
        'array',
        'NULL',
        'object',
        'integer',
        'double',
        'boolean',
        'string',
        'resource',
        'resource (closed)'
    ];

    $printableListArr = [
        'NULL',
        'object',
        'integer',
        'double',
        'boolean',
        'string',
        'resource',
        'resource (closed)'
    ];

    if (!in_array($type, $knownListArr)) {
        $msg = 'Unknown variable type: ' . $type;
        $text = null;
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException($msg);
    }

    if (!in_array($type, $printableListArr)) {
        $result = false;
    }

    if ($result && 
        $type === 'object' && 
        !method_exists($input, '__toString')) 
    {
        $result = false;
    }

    if ($result) {
        $text = (string) $input;
    } else {
        $text = null;
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Worth to note that `echo [];` will actually print `Array` string with PHP's Warning about array to string conversion. Also if you `echo null;` you will get an empty string `""` same if you do `echo false;`

Because `false` and `null` are completely different it might be good to handle such cases differently for human readability and present them for example as string: `false` and `NULL` instead of a misleading empty string for both of them.

Also `echo true;` prints string `1`, same as `echo 1;` but as already mentioned `echo false;` prints an empty string, not `0`.

As you can see detecting if a variable is printable is one thing, but printing it for example for debugging in an obvious way is another thing to take care of.

Comment: This is an interesting technique but since your function does not account for the exceptions that you mention (echo [], null, false, etc.) it should not pass a unit test until those exceptions are fixed.  Your test is incomplete therefore you are getting a false passing.  You could return false if empty($input) which should work.